# How to enable agora voice calling in background services with React Native?

Tags: react-native, background-service, agora

I am using agora voice calling to develop a react native voice calling app. But when I leave the call screen, I can't hear the other participant's voice. Even I use background services, the sate of the mute call and speaker mode is not working.

For now I'm using only the the `joinChannel()` to connect to the call channel.

Can someone give me some sample code on how to use the agora functions even though the calls are not on the screen?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.